# How was the plus-minus sign removed in these steps for proving a half-angle identity for tangent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-explanation, radicals

How was the plus-minus sign removed in the following solution? (see red rectangle)

[image]

Comment: You want to prove that $\sqrt{(1+\cos{\theta})^2}=1+\cos{\theta}$ and this holds iff $1+\cos{\theta}\geq 0$, but since the cosine is bounded by $1$ and $-1$ then $0\leq 1+\cos{\theta}\leq 2$ and so we are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivation is indeed faulty. You can make it rigorous by avoiding the square roots:
\begin{align}
\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}
&=\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta} \\[6px]
&=\frac{1-\cos^2\theta}{(1+\cos\theta)^2} \\[6px]
&=\frac{\sin^2\theta}{(1+\cos\theta)^2}
\end{align}
Therefore we have
$$
\Bigl\lvert\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\Bigr\rvert=\frac{\lvert\sin\theta\rvert}{1+\cos\theta}
$$
(note that $1+\cos\theta>0$, so no absolute value is needed in the denominator) and now we can observe that $\tan(\theta/2)$ and $\sin\theta$ have the same sign for every $\theta$ and so the absolute values can be removed.

In a different way:
$$
\frac{\sin2\alpha}{1+\cos2\alpha}=\frac{2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1+2\cos^2\alpha-1}=\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=\tan\alpha
$$
Now set $\alpha=\theta/2$.